# After adding my instances to my arraylist collection, how do I make it so that I can input the variables I need for my instances during iteration?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, iteration, instance

I'm practicing coding in Java as a beginner and I'm creating a project where I have a class car as well as other classes such as carParts, wheels, engine, and fuel.

I'm at the part where I'm adding instances of my carParts to my class Car and then adding them into an ArrayList where I am trying to iterate them.

I tried mapping out everything and I think I'm just getting confused as to what points to what.

What I had initially was something along the lines of

```
List<CarPart> carParts = new ArrayList<CarPart>();
carParts.add(myWheels.wheels(4));
carParts.add(myEngine.engine("good engine"));
carParts.add(myFuel.(100)); `
```

But that just ran those three before I even started iterating so I just simply changed it to

```
List<CarPart> carParts = new ArrayList<CarPart>();
carParts.add(myWheels);
carParts.add(myEngine);
carParts.add(myFuel); `
```

So that I can add in the variables during the iteration process

```
public class Car {

  Wheels myWheels = new Wheels();
  Engine myEngine = new Engine();
  Fuel myFuel = new Fuel();

  public void run() {

    //have to make wheels(4), engine("good engine"), and fuel(100)

    List<CarPart> carParts = new ArrayList<CarPart>();
    carParts.add(myWheels);
    carParts.add(myEngine);
    carParts.add(myFuel);

    /*
    myWheels.wheels(4);
    myEngine.engine("good engine");
    myFuel.fuel(10);    
    */

    Iterator<CarPart> carPartIterator = carParts.iterator();
    while (carPartIterator.hasNext()) {
        //run each individually
        System.out.println(carPartIterator.next());
    }
  }
}
```

When I add

```
carParts.add(myWheels.wheels(4));
carParts.add(myEngine.engine("good engine"));
carParts.add(myFuel.fuel(100));
```

I get the correct output but not in the correct spot so it's something like:

```
Correct Output for wheels
Correct Output for engine
Correct Output for fuel

null
null 
null
```

What I want is the correct outputs to be put into the place of `null`?

Comment: show us your `CarPart` class

Answer (score 0):

You don't have it listed in your post but here is what I will assume is happening.

```
List<CarPart> carParts = new ArrayList<CarPart>();
carParts.add(myWheels.wheels(4));
carParts.add(myEngine.engine("good engine"));
carParts.add(myFuel.(100));
```

The methods that you are adding have print ln statements inside them, but don't return a value.

What you seem to want from here is to print out those values when you iterate through car part. If all your Car Parts have a common method in common, i.e. `public String getString()` that would return a string of information you want, you could do the following:

```
Iterator<CarPart> carPartIterator = carParts.iterator();
while (carPartIterator.hasNext()) {
System.out.println(carPartIterator.next().getString());
}
```

The reason you are getting null values is because the methods you are calling are not returning a printable value such as a String. Again, I'm not sure of it but it is what I can infer from your post.

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) tutorial on returning values from methods for more info.